# PHP : Unexpected T_String while including jpeg image

Tags: php, jpeg

When including an image file in a php page using

```
include "images/filename.jpg";
```

I get the following error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in path_to_folder/images/filename.jpg on line 1
```

whereas this is working locally on my local wamp server. My site is hosted on hostmonster -- which I guess provides php5. Could the problem be with the host ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the other answers say, you are trying to execute the image (binary data) as php code. This is probably what you want:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile('image.jpeg');
```

Comment: `readfile()` will be more efficient, as it instructs PHP to read the file in chunks and dump it to the output stream.  `echo file_get_contents()` will buffer the entire image in memory and then write it out all at once, which can have serious performance implications if the image is anything but tiny.

Comment: @cdhowie in fact, they are all inefficient, and if there is a bottleneck, go for nginx and x_accel_redirect

Comment: @cdhowie: I did not know that and I choose to blindly believe you while I go read up on it :) Thanks!

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: And assembler is more efficient than PHP.  I know, there's always a better way to do things.  My point was that simple one-line change could mitigate a bad performance problem.  If we're going to re-engineer the OP's entire application stack, then hell, let's write the application layer in assembler.  It's more efficient, right?

Comment: well, for the OP's level it's all negligible nuances :)

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't make sense, and I don't see why it would work locally.  You're telling PHP to execute the image as PHP/HTML code, which will not work.

Comment: I've set header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes around the file path, anyway including an image in the code makes no sense. I can't imagine how it could work locally.

Comment: Edit: I've added the quotes in the post.

Comment: You need readfile(), not include (assuming headers are correct)

Answer (score 0):

you just don't understand what are you doing.

`include` is used for including another part of **PHP code** into your script.

To output a file you have to use `readfile()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your jpeg contains the sequence `<?`? Include is not meant to be used like this. You should use file_get_contents instead:

```php
echo file_get_contents("images/filename.jpg");
```